# Strange error on using spring-boot with gradle 2.12 and 2.13

Tags: spring, plugins, gradle, spring-boot

Below provided is the build.gradle, I have defined in the demo spring boot project and when i run gradle assemble or gradle boot run. This error comes if I apply the plugin spring-boot only.

I get the below error::

```
> To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked.
> Please consider using the daemon:
> https://docs.gradle.org/2.12/userguide/gradle_daemon.html. Parallel
> execution is an incubating feature.
> 
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 
> * What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':compileJava'.
> > Cannot change dependencies of configuration 'detachedConfiguration1' after it has been resolved.
> 
> 
> 
> * Exception is:
> 
> org.gradle.api.GradleException: Could not determine the dependencies
> of task ':compileJava'.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:67)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.getDependencies(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:55)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.addToTaskGraph(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:139)
>         at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.addTasks(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:98)
>         at org.gradle.execution.TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.configure(TaskNameResolvingBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.configure(DefaultTasksBuildExecutionAction.java:44)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:25)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.execution.ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.configure(ExcludedTaskFilteringBuildConfigurationAction.java:47)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:48)
>         at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.select(DefaultBuildConfigurationActionExecuter.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:143)
>         at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:140)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
>         at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
>         at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
>         at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>         at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:40)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>         at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>         at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
> Caused by: org.gradle.api.InvalidUserDataException: Cannot change
> dependencies of configuration 'detachedConfiguration1' after it has
> been resolved.
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.validateMutation(DefaultConfiguration.java:600)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$2.run(DefaultConfiguration.java:149)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.assertMutable(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:267)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.add(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:158)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.DelegatingDomainObjectSet.add(DelegatingDomainObjectSet.java:81)
>         at java_util_Set$add$1.call(Unknown Source)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement$_resolve_closure2.doCall(DependencyManagement.groovy:152)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement.resolve(DependencyManagement.groovy:152)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement.resolveIfNecessary(DependencyManagement.groovy:134)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement.getExclusions(DependencyManagement.groovy:128)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagement$getExclusions$1.call(Unknown
> Source)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementContainer.getExclusions(DependencyManagementContainer.groovy:104)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.DependencyManagementContainer$getExclusions$1.call(Unknown
> Source)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.findExcludedDependencies(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy:100)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.applyMavenExclusions(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy:77)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.this$2$applyMavenExclusions(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.execute(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy:72)
>         at io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.exclusions.ExclusionConfiguringAction.execute(ExclusionConfiguringAction.groovy)
>         at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
>         at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
>         at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
>         at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
>         at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
>         at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
>         at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy23.beforeResolve(Unknown Source)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.performPreResolveActions(DefaultConfiguration.java:388)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:369)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:346)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getBuildDependencies(DefaultConfiguration.java:414)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getBuildDependencies(Unknown
> Source)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext$TaskGraphImpl.getNodeValues(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:92)
>         at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker$GraphWithEmpyEdges.getNodeValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:202)
>         at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.doSearch(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:112)
>         at org.gradle.internal.graph.CachingDirectedGraphWalker.findValues(CachingDirectedGraphWalker.java:64)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.doResolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:76)
>         at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.resolve(CachingTaskDependencyResolveContext.java:65)
>         ... 61 more
```

Build.gradle ::

```
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
ext {
            springBootVersion = "1.3.5.RELEASE"
}
buildscript {
                        repositories { 
                                    maven { url "${gradleRepo_local}"}

                                    mavenCentral()
                                    jcenter()

                        }
                          dependencies {

                                  classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}") 
                          }
            }
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') 
}
```

Please help if any body has solution to this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange error is a result of some poor diagnostics in the dependency management plugin that Spring Boot uses. They've been improved as part of [this issue](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin/issues/81).

The root cause of the problem is that you only have buildscript repositories declared in your `build.gradle`. That's causing a failure when Gradle tries to perform some dependency resolution. To fix the problem, add the following to your build script:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, That works. Actually, mavenCentral was behind my corporate proxy.